# Ignored JSON element changeset.Artifact during processing of this request

Tags: rest, rally

How to link a changeset to an artifact?  I specify a defect in a rest client when creating a changeset

```
{"changeset":{
"Message":"1234 abcd",
"Artifact":"/defect/567890",
"SCMRepository":"/scmrepository/123456",
"Revision":"1",
"CommitTimestamp":"2013-10-08"
}}
```

a changeset is created but not linked to the defect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is `Artifacts` collection on a changeset object, but no `Artifact` attribute on changeset.

To link to an artifact, modify the Request Body as follows:

```
{"changeset":{
"Message":"1234 abcd",
"Artifacts":{"Artifact":"/defect/14537223513"},
"SCMRepository":"/scmrepository/5960544988",
"Revision":"1",
"CommitTimestamp":"2013-10-08"
}}
```